Partitioning Rocky Linux 9 on AWS ec2
I have a strange issue while working with partitions on my Rocky Linux 9 (non LVM) EC2 instance on AWS.
GOAL: I would like to enlarge a little (5GB) my ebs in order to create a new partition and a new xfs filesystem to mount on it /tmp to have it separated from root partition
MY ATTEMPT: I started to remove from /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg growpart and resizefs to prevent cloud-init to automatically enlarge root partition:
sudo sed -i '/ - growpart/d' /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg

sudo sed -i '/ - resizefs/d' /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg

Then I enlarged my EBS volume from AWS console, from 15GB to 20GB
After that on my ec2 I see, from lsblk ,that the disk has the desired size, so I started my work
I created a new partition with fdisk
I created a filesystem on it: mkfs.xfs -f -L tmp /dev/nvme0n1p5
Until here, every reboot works
I modified /etc/fstab to mount at boot the partition
LABEL=tmp /tmp xfs defaults,noatime,nodev,nosuid,noexec 1 2

then I re-mount (mount -a) to ensure everything works
Tmp is now on my new paritition
Then I reboot my ec2 and the OS is stuck, I cannot connect to it anymore
QUESTIONS: What is wrong with all of this? What am I missing? tmpfs? I just need a separated partition, only one this time but can be more in the future, is there a guide to to this on aws?

I'm not familiar with EC2 per se, but why don't you just add an additional volume instead of messing around with the partitions?

I think I found the issue and the root cause is tmp.mount. In many guides I found online that to mount tmp with an entry in fstab I need to disable that service with
systemctl mask tmp.mount
With this command, that should disable the service, the corresponding unit is redirect to null, via symbolic link I suppose
[root@rocky9 ~]# ls -l /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 May 23 17:20 /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount -> /dev/null
[root@rocky9 ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount
[root@rocky9 ~]#
Operation that seemed useless since on Rocky 9 the configuration is that one by default.
Only in this page
https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_AlmaLinux_OS_9_v1.0.0_L1_Server.audit:3b133929eff69c1cd4b4655a7c7542bf
I found the command
[root@rocky9 ~]# systemctl unmask tmp.mount
Removed "/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount".
That completely remove the file and I'm able to mount via fstab.
I don't know exactly the meaning and the action of mask and unmask commands, but that's an other topic.
